# Simple Android keyboard supporting swipe

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

I'm looking for a simple Android keyboard that supports swipe typing and emojis.

I don't want bells and whistles like stickers/gifs/etc.

The stock keyboard that came on my Note 4 has exactly these features but is not particularly appealing or easy to type with.

Comment: I cannot name a specific candidate – but while waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to take a look at [my corresponding app-list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards). Keyboards with swipe support can be found in two of the groups there (all-in-one and specific).

Comment: Thanks! I am checking some of the ones in your list now, MultiLing looks promising.

Comment: That would have been my choice as well (the second one, MultiLingO, as it is more up-to-date) :) Be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) when you've tried it; even if you're still looking for something else, that might help others!

Comment: Thanks, I did, it's not perfect but I think the more I use it the easier it gets. I've become too accustomed to how accurate gboard's autocorrect and swipe are, so I'm trying to get more accurate with my typing. As far as I can tell it does not learn your typing style.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've included a link to its playstore page, and upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently I am using [MultiLing O Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh). It works pretty well but the auto-correct can be somewhat overzealous, it often replaces minor typos with something totally different. There are a lot of settings which can be adjusted however and I am playing with them to see if I can improve the behavior. I think it's also a matter of having become lazy and inaccurate in my typing after using "smarter" keyboards for a long time.